# What i can do when buildbot fail during buildstep

Tags: python, buildbot

all. When buildstep fail, Can i get trigged and write script to do something, send email  or try catch for that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the
[mail notifier](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/current/manual/cfg-statustargets.html#mailnotifier)
or the
[irc bot](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/current/manual/cfg-statustargets.html#irc-bot)
to report on the success or failure of builds.

There is a particularly direct way to do that for particular build steps, but I suspect that the above are sufficient. In any case, they will be able to include information about what steps failed.